# Write an array on.plist

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem. I have this file dictionary .plist:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>2</key>
    <array>
        <string>a</string>
        <string>b</string>
        <string>c</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So now I read this file in this way:

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dictionary" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *contentArray = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

NSMutableArray *dic = [contentArray  objectForKey:@"2"];

    NSLog(@"Numero di elementi del dictionary corrispondente a 2: %i", [dic count]);

    for (int i = 0; i < [dic count]; ++i) {
        NSString *temp = [dic objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Stringa = %@\n", temp);
    }
```

Now I want to modify the array:

```
[dic replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"ok"];
```

and I want to write it on the dictionary.plist and I try this:

```
[contentArray writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

[contentArray release];
```

But this code doesn't work, and I receive an error, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is this file being stored in the Resource Bundle or Documents folder? My understanding is that you can't alter a file stored in the Resource Bundle as it is part of the "installation" files

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide the error, I assume the problem might be that

```
NSMutableDictionary * contentArray = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];
```

only creates a mutable container (you can change the content of contentArray, but not the objects (leaves) inside of it.

If you want mutable leaves, use NSPropertyListSerialization instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary * contentArray = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: plistPath] mutabilityOption: NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format: nil errorDescription: nil];
```

Comment: Thanks IRaivis, no it works fine in this way, I read the plist in the correct mode, I can't write it, so you think that it depends on how I read the file?